# caffe UBUNTU 17.04 python 2.7

Tags: python, ubuntu, caffe

Is there any way to install caffe on ubuntu 17.04 with python 2.7 support?

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html

```
sudo apt install caffe-cpu
```

Installs caffe but only supports python 3. I want to install caffe with python 2.7 support.

Thank you.